# How to write directive to hide div clicking anywhere on page?

Tags: angularjs

This is first time that I am writing directive. I am trying to write directive to hide my div.This is my html:

```
<div id="loggedIn" close-logged-in class="fade-show-hide"  ng-show="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

I find element but when I click anywhere on page I dont get anything.Can someone help me how to write directive so that when shown user click anywhere on page, it will hide that div.Any suggestion?

```
'use strict';
    angular.module("accountModule").directive('closeLoggedIn', function () {
        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var loggedIn = angular.element(document.getElementById("loggedIn"));
                console.log(loggedIn);

                var isClosed = false;

                loggedIn.on('click', function (e) {

                    console.log("LOGGED IN ON CLICK ", loggedIn);

                });
            }
        }
```

I dont get this message "LOGGED IN ON CLICK"

Comment: Can you show the final HTML (the relevant parts of it), not the Razor template. We don't even see where the directive is defined

Comment: You want to hide the div when the user clicks anywhere on the page or when the user clicks on the div?

Comment: i want to hide it when user clicks anyhere on page ..if that div is open

Comment: @NewDev how u mean u dont even see where the directive is defined?

Comment: @None, ah... I misread and thought that your directive is `accountModule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `getElementById("loggedIn")` The `<div>` is already there for you as the `element` argument in the link function. There should rarely be any need to reference elements by their ID's in Angular.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mnSfW0t1T7LWgOQoiXT?p=preview)

**html**

```
<div hide-when-click-anywhere default-display='block'>Click anywhere to hide me</div>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.isHidden = false;
});

app
.directive('hideWhenClickAnywhere', function ($window) {
  return {

    // bind a local scope (i.e. on link function scope) property 
    // to the value of default-display attribute in our target <div>.
    scope: {
      defaultDisplay: '@'
    },

    restrict: 'A',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var el = element[0];

      // set default css display value. Use 'block' if 
      // the default-display attribute is undefined
      el.style.display = scope.defaultDisplay || 'block';  

      angular.element($window).bind('click', function(){

        // Toggle display value.
        // If you just want to hide the element and
        // that's it then remove this if block
        if(el.style.display === 'none'){
          el.style.display = scope.defaultDisplay || 'block';  
          return;
        }

        el.style.display = 'none';

      });
    } 

  };

});
```

**Update**

Ok after reading you comments I think this might be more what you're trying to achieve;

Take note of this line in the `<button>` element defined in *template.html*:

```
ng-click="contentHidden = !contentHidden; $event.stopPropagation();"
```

`$event.stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling up and triggering the 'click' listener we have defined on `$window` in our directive.

[DEMO2](http://plnkr.co/edit/lx87lJraTOWGtQHt0dev?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.hideOnStart = true;
});

app
.directive('panel', function ($window) {
  return {

    scope: {
      // this creates a new 'isolate' scope
      // '=' sets two-way binding between the directive 
      // scope and the parent scope
      // read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile
      hideOnStart: '=',
      panelTitle: '@'
    },

    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'template.html',

    restrict: 'E',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 

      console.log(scope.panelTitle)

      // div content is hidden on start
      scope.contentHidden = scope.hideOnStart || false;

      angular.element($window).bind('click', function(e){

        // check if the content is already hidden
        // if true then ignore
        // if false hide the content
        if(!scope.contentHidden){
          scope.contentHidden = true;

          // we have to manually update the scope
          // because Angular does not know about this event
          scope.$digest();
        }

      });
    } 

  };

});
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">

    <div class="panel-title">{{panelTitle}}
      <button 
        type="button" 
        class="close" 
        ng-click="contentHidden = !contentHidden; $event.stopPropagation();"
        aria-label="Close"
      >
        <span ng-hide="contentHidden">close</span>
        <span ng-hide="!contentHidden">open</span>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="panel-body" ng-hide="contentHidden"  ng-transclude></div>

</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <panel panel-title="Title" hide-on-start="hideOnStart">
            <h4>Content...</h4>
            <p>foo bar baz</p>
          </panel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Problem with your version is that i first need to click on div to opened it and then when i click anywhere else that it show and hide that div... and i need if user click anywhere and div is close nothing happend and if div is opened and if user click anywhere then to close that div...if u know what i mean? :)

Comment: Not sure I understand you. You want the `<div>` to be hidden at first?

Comment: If you don't want the toggle functionality just remove the if block as per the comments in the code.

Comment: yes i want that div is hidden at first and if user click anywhere on page while div is hidden it need to remain hidden... if i click on that div it need to show me that div and then if i click on div or anywhere on page it need to be hidden

Comment: in your case right now its hidden at first but when i click on div nothing happend and then when i click anywhere on page it show div

Comment: P.S. I see that works on plunker but for me its not on my project :(

Comment: Updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: it helps a lot :) tnx dude :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83731/discussion-between-none-and-matt-herbstritt).